# When acquiring a domain name for product xyz, is it still important to buy .net and .org versions too?

Tags: domains, top-level-domains

I am buying a domain name for service xyz and obviously I have bought `.com` in the first place. In the past it was automatic to also buy the `.net` and `.org` versions. However, I've been asking myself, **why would I do that**? To serve customers who mistakenly enter a different TLD? (Would someone accidentally do that these days?) To avoid a chance that competition will acquire those TLDs and play some dirty game on my customers?

If there is a good reason, or a few, to buy the .net and .org versions these days I'd like to see those listed. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If someone mistypes the tld part, you would be safe with some more domains, but what if the customer mistypes your company in the first place? If your company is, let's say "peach ltd", you would not only have to buy peach.com, peach.org, peach.net and so on, but also paech.com or peahc.com and all the other combinations. **There are just too many possibilities of mistyping a company name or a domain name!**

For instance, Google with one more "o" in the .com domain name still works, but not with 3 more. So where do you stop buying mistype-domains?

Do good seo with your site, build up a good picture of your company and it's name and care for some back links. This way, the customer will find your major domain very fast and competitors may get in legal trouble if you prepared your brand name accordingly.

My personal suggestion is to buy the .com and your countries tld and that's it for the beginning. While your company grows, it will be no problem to buy all the other domains if that's really an issue for you, but improving your site with that money is a much better investment in my eyes.

Answer (score 1):

You pretty much answered your own question.

When people buy up all the TLDs for a specific domain they are doing it to secure the brand so you don't have to deal with issues like competitors, angry customers slandering your brand, etc.

Comment: The problem is that there are hundreds of TLDs, I certainly don't have a budget to acquire all of them and I wonder if getting just the two of them would make any difference.

Comment: You really want to hit the major ones; .com, .net and .org and if you are in a country I would do that country's TLD. All the other country TLD's I would just leave alone.

Answer (score 0):

Although its nice belt and braces approach to own the other domain, it my oppinion its not really nessacery as most of your traffic will come through search so for someone to compete with you they would need to have content on those sites and be backlinks so that they ranked for it.

That said if they are free i would buy them as they only cost about $10 and they are kind of worth having. If someone else already has them i wouldnt be too concerned unless they are running a site that you think would compete with yours in search results.